# Video embedded using iFrame library for iOS disappears on the emulator after start playing

Tags: ios, xcode, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using the iFrame library for iOS to display youtube videos.
On emulators, with iOS versions 11-13 the video disappears right after pressing play.
Tested on iOS 11.4, 12.0, 12.4, 13.7.
On real devices, the video didn't disappear.
Tried to run it on Xcode 12.5 and Xcode 11.7 with the same results.